# css youtube embed fluid both horizontally and vertically

Tags: css, youtube, embed, fluid

Is it possible using pure css to get a youtube embed to be fluid both horizontally and vertically?

Basically this means that the video aspect ratio is kept at all times, no matter the width/height of the parent. For example, if the parent div was very wide and short, the video would have gaps on both sides. If the parent was very thin and tall, the video would have gaps on the top and bottom.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I do it, compliments to http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LAtPJ/)

```
<div class="thumbnailContainer video_embed">
    <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Kdgt1ZHkvnM?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>

        .thumbnailContainer
        {
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .thumbnailContainer.video_embed
        {
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 56.25%;
            padding-top: 30px;
            height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .thumbnailContainer.video_embed iframe
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

Comment: I asked this question directly after reading the given link, as it only addresses fluid width.